# Querying database within a while loop

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to determine whether a database has been initialised by executing a query and examining the exit code. If the exit code is 0 then I know that the database query has been accepted and the database should be initialised.

I cannot use `pg_isready` because the postgres version is prior to 9.3 so I have developed the following code:

```
while (( $(su -l postgres -c "psql -d db_name -c 'select count(1) from table_name' > /dev/null 2>&1") != 0 )) 
        do
            echo "waiting for database to initialise"
            sleep 10
        done
```

Running `$(su -l postgres -c "psql -d db_name -c 'select count(1) from table_name' > /dev/null 2>&1"` on its own returns an exit code of 0 however I am getting an error message when it is used within the loop:

```
((: != 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "!= 0 ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the return value directly.

```
while ! cmd
do
    ...
done
```